# Converting a string looking list as a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

The HTTP response header for 'packages_list' returns the following, which is a list looking string. How do i convert this to an actual list? I have tried typecasting the string as a list which didn't work. I am not keen on doing find and replace or strip. Once I have the list I am creating a windows forms with buttons with text for each of the items in list. Any help is appreciated

I am using IronPython 2.6 (yes, I know its old but cant move away for backward compatibility reasons)

```
['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']


httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(base_server_url)
httpConn.request("POST", urlparser.path, params)
response = httpConn.getresponse()
headers = dict(response.getheaders())
print headers['packages_list']
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. to my disappointment IronPython 2.6 has a bug apparently and json.loads blows up  and it does not have ast package in built. and I cant installl for backward compatibility reasons

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MMI_RADIA_PKG\IronPython 2.6\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 307, in loads
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MMI_RADIA_PKG\IronPython 2.6\Lib\json\scanner.py", line 42, in iterscan
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scanner'

IronPython bug reference http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/25787

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach, IMHO, would be to use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> s = "['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']"
>>> s
"['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik for taking time to help. Sadly there is no ast in IronPython 2.6

Answer (score 1):

You can to check if the string is a valid python type

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['Admin', 'MMX_G10_Asia', 'MMX_G10_London', 'MMX_G10_Readonly', 'MMX_Credit_Readonly', 'MMX_Govies_ReadOnly']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fred. unfortunately the stupid IronPython 2.6 does not have ast package :-(

Comment: [This is quite surprising !](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/ast.html#ast-helpers)

Comment: Looks like I am using the oldest of 2.6 series
'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MMI_RADIA_PKG\IronPython 2.6\ipy.exe" C:/Users//PycharmProjects/MultiPackageSupport/temp/temp1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//PycharmProjects/MultiPackageSupport/temp/temp1.py", line 1, in C:/Users//PycharmProjects/MultiPackageSupport/temp/temp1.py
ImportError: No module named ast
Process finished with exit code 1
'

Comment: Hello mate, I cant, it has been distributed to 100s of user desktops. so my work should work on their PCs with their version of IronPython. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert this string to JSON format and then read it in:

```
import json
s = headers['packages_list'].replace("'", '"')
result = json.loads(s)
```

Comment: Do you really need to replace all `'`' with `"`? Doesn't JSON use either one to enclose a string literal?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice not sure what JSON specification says, but `json.load` only accepts `"` as string delimiter.

Comment: The example at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html says otherwise: `>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')`.

Comment: Oh wait...I had it backwards. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but I am going with the below. Thanks again everyone for the help !

```
headers = dict(response.getheaders())
print headers['packages_list']
result = headers['packages_list'].replace("'",'')
result = result.replace("[","")
result = result.replace("]", "")
print result
package_list = result.split(",") 
print "the 2nd item in teh list is ", package_list[1]
```